# check for valid user session

Tags: ios, quickblox

Does the QuickBlox SDK for iOS include a method for checking / storing a valid user session?

Unless the user has specifically logged out, they should be automatically logged back in. Does the SDK have a built in mechanism for dealing with this or do I need to store the username and password, if I'm storing the info what needs to be stored for a FB login?

Answer (score 4):

For example, you created session with facebook login

```
QBASessionCreationRequest *extendedAuthRequest = [QBASessionCreationRequest request];
extendedAuthRequest.socialProvider = @"facebook";
extendedAuthRequest.socialProviderAccessToken = @"BAAE74iZBvNR0BAFCnyIIvdbdslDZCbIyzqDtT1oWg4dYYQoUl2tsBGMAZCFJX1x2x0h116OF0rObZC3WwtjjtS9rHiwcsvwvlI4pk0RTObCZAvkfUZCGxatsLykeWmC4";

[QBAuth createSessionWithExtendedRequest:extendedAuthRequest delegate:self];
```

Your session will be expired in 2 hours after last request to QuickBlox API. And next, you will get "**Required session does not exist**"

you should recreate session manually in this case (i mean repeat above query)

To check session expiration date use next snippet:

```
NSDate *sessionExpiratioDate = [QBBaseModule sharedModule].tokenExpirationDate;
```

Comment: where to write `[QBSettings enableSessionExpirationAutoHandler:YES];` ?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko, how to check wether session expired or not with `NSDate *sessionExpiratioDate = [QBBaseModule sharedModule].tokenExpirationDate;` ?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko, one more question, is `sessionExpiratioDate` will be update every time when I make a new API call (and not a session creation)? For e.g. I created session right now, so the `sessionExpiratioDate` will be set to next 2 hours for expiration, if within one hour I'll make another request, will it increase(update) `sessionExpiratioDate` too?

Answer (score 2):

SDK itself will not support for session management like in Web Applications. This is due to the concept of Client Server communication. There are concepts in mobile application development to check for a valid user session. One approach would be to pass a cookie value together with each request in the header. Each user should be granted a unique cookie from server side and that cookie needs to be passed again to the web services to authorize the current user.