# Quickblox - Rermember app session via REST

Tags: quickblox

I am using the REST version of the api in Appcelerator Titanium.

I am authenticating the app and then later authenticating the user with a username and password.

However, if I close the app the session is lost and the user needs to login again.

Is there any way around this, other than storing the users login / password in the app, which i don't really want to do?

Ideally I would like to renew the token and carry on...

I have seen this answer ([check for valid user session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830051/check-for-valid-user-session)) but it doesn't seem valid in my case as it is using the facebook id to login.

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expiration time for token is 2 hours after last query. If you will perform query with expired token - you will receive error **Required session does not exist**. In this case you have to recreate session.

Also, each API response contains header **QB-Token-ExpirationDate** which contains Token expiration date.

QuickBlox uses 2h for security reasons.

At the moment only one way is to store login/pass in app

There are lots of secure mechanisms to do such things, for example Apple iOS Keychain API https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: Some times,I found this error, when user login in application with quickblox. Can you suggest me where i missed.